# OpenMDAO: conditional statement depending on the number of iterations

Tags: openmdao

During an optimisation using OpenMDAO, is there any way to access the number of iterations or the values of the design variables in previous iterations during optimisation?

I would like to create a conditional statement depending on the corresponding number of iterations.

I have created a continuous function representing discrete points linked by exponential functions. I would like to increase the exponent of the intermediate function with the number of iterations so that it penalises the intermediate values and the optimisation converges close to one of the discrete values.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like a form of continuation/smoothing. I can suggest two different approaches:

1. Set a reasonable max-iteration limit on the optimizer and add an outside for-loop around the call to `run_driver`. You could even adapt the iteration limit after each stopping point is reached. Start with a very small iteration limit, and let it grow as you converge more.

   Pros:

   - fairly simple to implement
   - uses existing OpenMDAO Driver APIs

   Cons:

   - Limited ability to set your own stoping conditions (only really have iteration limit)
   - Restarting the optimization does not preserve the prior hessian approximation and may lead to poor convergence for quasi-newton method
2. Skip the OpenMDAO driver interface, and roll your own. [This approach](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/RevHack2020/blob/master/solution_approaches/no_driver.md) was suggested in the [2020 OpenMDAO Reverse Hackathon](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/RevHack2020), for users who find the OpenMDAO Driver interface doesn't meet their need.

   Pros:

   - A lot more flexibility
   - total control

   Cons:

   - A lot more work